# Is it possible to run multiple ontime events when the first one is recurring?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using `Application.Ontime` to run 3 procedures in a Workbook which will act as timers. The first one is just a reminder that the user has the Workbook locked for editing after 10 minutes. The other two check for inactivity based on Workbook events (`SheetCalculate`,`SheetSelectionChange` etc). After 10 minutes of inactivity a userform is called to warn them that they've been idle for 10 minutes, and that after 15 minutes, the form will automatically save and close.

What I wanted to do is alter the first ontime event to **repeat** every 10 minutes just to let them know they are still working in a non Read-Only session. Easy enough, I just reschedule the procedure at the end of the procedure that is called.

The issue I'm having though, is that it will repeat every 10 minutes as intended, but the other two (idle checks) that are scheduled, won't run until the recurring one is cancelled. **And** even though they are scheduled for `Now` + x minutes when the Workbook is opened, the timers do not start until the first scheduled procedure (EditTimeCheck) is finished. So even if I don't have it repeat, if the workbook were opened and inactive from the start, the first alert will pop up after 10 minutes, then the warning will trigger 10 minutes after that, then the save and close procedure 15 minutes after that. Meaning instead of closing after 15 minutes, it will close after 35. I may not fully understand `Application.Ontime` I suppose.

I gather I can schedule multiple at once, but is it possible to have them actually function the way I thought they would? I've confirmed this is how they are behaving by commenting out the code for each procedure and adding `Debug.Print` With the procedure name and a timestamp.

```
Public IdleTimeClose As Double
Public IdleTime As Double
Public TimeOpen As Double
```

---

```
    Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    TimeOpen = Now + TimeValue("00:10:00")
    IdleTime = Now + TimeValue("00:15:00")
    IdleTimeClose = Now + TimeValue("00:15:00")

        If Not ThisWorkbook.ReadOnly Then
        Application.OnTime TimeOpen, "EditTimeCheck"
        Application.OnTime IdleTimeClose, "CloseWB"
        End If
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub EditTimeCheck()

MsgBox "You've had the Workbook open for editing for x minutes"

TimeOpen = Now + TimeValue("00:10:00")
Application.OnTime TimeOpen, "EditTimeCheck"

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub IdleWarning()

With inactiveUF
  .StartUpPosition = 0
  .Left = Application.Left + (0.5 * Application.Width) - (0.5 * .Width)
  .Top = Application.Top + (0.55 * Application.Height) - (0.5 * .Height)
  .Show False
End With

End Sub
```

---

```
    Sub CloseWB()
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks("Copy of Requests Tracker.xlsm")

With wb
    .Save
    .Close True
'End With
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub StartIdle()

IdleTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")
IdleTimeClose = Now + TimeValue("00:00:15")

Application.OnTime IdleTime, "IdleWarning"
Application.OnTime IdleTimeClose, "CloseWB"

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub StopIdle()

On Error Resume Next
Application.OnTime IdleTime, "IdleWarning", , False
Application.OnTime IdleTimeClose, "CloseWB", , False

End Sub
```

---

Example of one of the Workbook events to reset the timer on the idle procedures

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Call StopIdle
    Call StartIdle
End Sub
```

Thanks for any insight, I haven't been able to find a clear cut answer in my searches.

Comment: I have never tried two timers in the same workbook (if I recall correctly). But I have had several workbooks open with reoccurring ontimes running with no problems

Comment: Use 1 timer for 5 minutes, and where the `(now() - offset_from_hour) / 15` is equal to the rounded version (no decimals), you trigger the 15 minute code, and similar for the 10 minute code.